# Externalize logback-spring.xml programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

My `application.properties` are loaded programmatically 
using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. So setting `logging.config` in `application.properties` (eg: `logging.config=file:/home/dev-01/conf/logback.xml`)

in the `application.properties` won't work since logging occurs early in the lifecycle and therefore cannot read values from `application.properties`.

I need to externalize the `logback.xml` as there are property values that needs to be configured depending on the environment. If I can externalize it, it can be manage by support/operations without developer intervention. Also, it is easy to maintain without redirection from `application.properties`. Meaning I can set property values in the `logback.xml` file itself.

I saw solution of adding the VM options during startup. I have not tried it but I am just wondering if I can load the `logback.xml` programmatically (similar to my `application.properties`).

Comment: Spring-boot automatically searches for `logback.xml` or `logback-spring.xml` file in your classpath and loads it on startup. Setting the `logging.config` prop in app.props is not necessary.

Comment: @lazarov I need logback.xml or logback-spring.xml loaded from external path.

Answer (score 2):

i use a configuration like this to achieve that:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" debug="false">
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
    <include file="${CONFDIR}/config/logback-config.xml" />
</configuration>
```

and then you place another logback config in that location and changes to that file will be refreshed every 10 seconds

Comment: This I think should be set as the solution, it solved my issue. Only slight change I made was to set <include file="config/logback-config.xml" /> instead of <include file="${CONFDIR}/config/logback-config.xml" /> since ${CONFDIR} wasn't defined in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Loading `logback.xml` programmatically does not seem to be a viable solution. My scenario is `application.properties` is loaded programmatically (from an external path) so setting `logging.config` property in `application.properties` file will not work. Note, it works using the default `application.properties` in classpath. I think the most pragmatic approach is passing `-Dlogging.config=/[some-path]/logback.xml`. This option works for me and updating logging levels (for debugging purpose) without redeploying the jar file.

Setting the logback.xml configuration **scan** to true will refresh the settings if logback.xml is updated.

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
  ...
</configuration>
```